# how to populate Map<id,List<Employee>> i want to map Profit Center with a list of Employees associated to that Profit Center

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I want to populate Profit Center with a list of Employees associated to that Profit Center. The code below is not allowing me to add the employees into the List and put the values into the Map.

[image]

Comment: Why won't it let you? Are you getting an error? Does it simply not work? Your code doesn't "do" anything with the work it does, it's just shuffling data around.

Comment: Please include your code as *text*, not images.

Comment: The error I get is on Line 31. The error is " Incompatible key type Set<Id> for Map<Id,List<Employee__c>> at line 31 column 28"
 @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the set as a key, which is not correct. You meant to use the Profit_Center__c Id value. Here's an optimized version that does that. Note that this code doesn't "do" anything by itself; I presume that you'll have to add additional logic that does something productive later.

```
public class EmployeeTriggerHelper {
  public static void checkEmployee(Employee__c[] trgNew) {
    Map<Id, List<Employee__c>> organized = new Map<Id, List<Employee__c>>();
    for(Employee__c record: trgNew) {
      organized.put(record.Profit_Center__c, new Employee__c[0]);
    }
    for(Employee__c record: [SELECT Profit_Center__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Profit_Center__c = :organized.keySet()]) {
      organized.get(record.Profit_Center__c).add(record);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let SOQL do the work for you.  You can query `Profit_Center__c` to get a list of profit centers, with a subquery for `Employee__c` using the existing relationship.  Also there is no need to loop through Employee to get a list of Profit Centers, you can use an outer join query to get them as well.

```
List<Profit_Center__c> profitCenters = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Employees__r) FROM Profit_Center__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Profit_Center__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Id IN :trgNew)];
```

The result of the above query is a list of `Profit_Center__c` records, with their `Employee__c` children objects.

Here is a link to Salesforce documentation to help you understand [SOQL Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

```
for(Profit_Center__c profitCenter : profitCenters)
{
    for(Employee__c employee : profitCenter.Employees__r)
    {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```